# footer располагается не по центру

Tags: html, css

footer взят из Bootstrap 4, вот он:

```
      <footer class="mastfoot mt-auto" style="border-top: 2px solid rgb(215,215,215); padding-top: 5px; max-width: 80%;">
        <div class="inner">
          <p style="color: rgb(129,140,153);">done 07/31/21, by <a target=”_blank” style="color: #5173e6" href="https://www.t.me/lagoonykeeper">@lagoony.keeper</a></p>
        </div>
      </footer>
```

Я задаю ему максимальную ширину в 80% от родителя, и он съезжает влево:
[image: footer съезжает влево]

Comment: Вы уменьшили его ширину до 80%, но никак не центрировали. Попробуйте установить значение auto для внешних отступов слева и справа: `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto`

Comment: спасибо, забыл о такой очевидной вещи... помогло, прошу прощения за столь глупый вопрос :)